# Density function related to Brownian motion

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I am dealing with a question listed below. I am trying to use the running maximum of Brownian motion to deal with the problem, but it does not work out.

Let $ \tau_{M}=\inf\{t;W(t)=M\},M>0,$ and

$X(t)=\begin{cases}
W(t) & \text{if }t<\tau_{m}\\
M & \text{if }t\geq\tau_{m}
\end{cases}$

Find the density function of $X(t)$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Is $W$ a Brownian motion ?

Comment: Yes it is a Brownian motion.